# Translate Recursive Defined Structs to Julia for C Interface

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, julia

I want to write a Julia interface to a C library. For me it is necessary to 
translate a C struct to a Julia type. This is necessary because i want to make 
a call to a C function using ccall.

```
    struct my_struct {

        struct my_struct * child; 
        int a;

        struct A_st{
            int c; 
            int (*f1) (struct my_struct * eqn); 
            int (*f2) (struct my_struct * eqn); 
            int (*f3) (struct my_struct * eqn); 
        } A; 
    };
```

I know that Julia has a problem with circular defined types
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/269
"Simple" defined structs i have already mapped to a julia type but with this one i have problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the inner struct first, then use it as a member:

```
struct A_st
  c::Cint
  f1::Ptr{Void}
  f2::Ptr{Void}
  f3::Ptr{Void}
end

struct my_struct
  child::Ptr{my_struct}
  a::Cint
  A::A_st
end
```

Untested, but the Julia alignments look correct:

```
julia> map(i -> Int(fieldoffset(my_struct,i)), 1:3)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  0
  8
 16

julia> map(i -> Int(fieldoffset(A_st,i)), 1:4)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
  0
  8
 16
 24
```

vs

```
clang -cc1 -fdump-record-layouts t.cpp

*** Dumping AST Record Layout
         0 | struct my_struct
         0 |   struct my_struct * child
         8 |   int a
        16 |   struct my_struct::A_st A
        16 |     int c
        24 |     int (*)(struct my_struct *) f1
        32 |     int (*)(struct my_struct *) f2
        40 |     int (*)(struct my_struct *) f3
           | [sizeof=48, dsize=48, align=8,
           |  nvsize=48, nvalign=8]
```

Comment: Hi thanks you very much! It there any reason to use struct instead of type? Best Max

Comment: Yes: `struct` (`immutable` before 0.6) has C-compatible memory layout and the member struct will be stored inline.

Comment: Ah ok. I start understanding. 
In Julia 0.5 i have to use immutable or type http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/. 
Now they have changed the keywords 
https://github.com/yoda90/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md. 
But how can i be sure to be compatible to 0.5 and 0.6 ?

Comment: Right now `immutable` will work fine on both 0.5 and 0.6, without a deprecation warning. Eventually it will be deprecated and removed. [Compat.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl) is useful in some cases, but it might not be worth the trouble unless you have many structs (changing a few manually is not difficult).